# Deleting row in listview using Command + CommandParameter in WPF + MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, command, commandparameter

I want to delete a row in ListView Control using Command and CommandParameter like below.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="X">
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding CriteriaId}"/>
           <Button Name="btnDeleteCriterion" Tag="{Binding CriteriaId}" Content="{Binding CriteriaId}" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" 
                                                             Command="{Binding DeleteCriterionCommand}" 
                                                                        DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                                             CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Tag}"
                                                                        />
        <StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I am trying to grab the Tag property of the Button and pass it to Command like above and than remove it from list like so.

> Edited, above XAML and added  a TextBlock which uses the same binding as the Button's Tag and Content, but somehow Button doesn't get the value but TextBlock does!?

```
    public void DeleteCriterion(object criterionId)
    {
        int crtId = (int)criterionId;
        Criterion crt = _criteria.FirstOrDefault((c) => c.CriterionId == crtId);
        if (crt != null)
            _criteria.Remove(crt);
    }
```

but I always get criterionId parameter as null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're explicitly setting the DataContext within the button, when you're doing a binding like `{Binding SomeProperty}` it will assume that SomeProperty is in the DataContext that you just set. Try using a more explicit binding like:

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=DataContext.CriteriaId}"
```

which will give you the correct DataContext's `CriteriaID` like it is for the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Yes that worked :). But just a little correction `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=DataContext.CriteriaId}"`. Thanks a Bunch Jakub.

Comment: Jakub, I had added the StackPanel to accommodate TextBlock. Now that I won't need TextBlock, I won't need the StackPanel either. In that case, If I set Path="GridViewColumn" in the answer your suggested, it doesn't work. Do I have to keep the StackPanel to make this work?

Comment: I believe you should be able to bind to the `DataTemplate`

Comment: I tried this, `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataTemplate}, Path=DataContext.CriteriaId}"` but it didn't work either.

Comment: D'oh! I didn't realize `DataTemplate` doesn't have a `DataContext` property. Try this: `{Binding Path=CriteriaId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`. If that doesn't work, just cheat and use a button inside a stackframe.

Comment: nope, it didn't work. so i guess I'll have to stick with the StackPanel for now :). Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your button's `Tag` isn't null (if it is null, you have a different problem), I don't see a reason that you can't bind directly to `CriterionId` like you do with `Tag`.

Comment: Hi Jakub, I added a TextBlock above with the same Binding as Button's Tag, but the TextBlock gets updated and not the Tag or the Content of the button!

Comment: Oh I think it must be something to do with the DataContext of the button!